# How do I get my image to follow my mouse?

Tags: java, image, swing, mousemove, mouse-listeners

How do I get my image to follow my mouse anywhere on the screen?

The below code makes the image move along the x axis.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class PlayerTwo implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
   public static int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 15;
   public static int PLAYER_WIDTH = 15;

   private Image p2Image = null;
   private static int x = 0;
   private static int y = 0;
   private int heightPosition = 0;

    Main main = null;

    public PlayerTwo(Image pi, Main m ){
        main = m;
        p2Image = pi;
        y = (int)((Main.WIDTH*2)+(PLAYER_WIDTH*2));
        heightPosition = Main.HEIGHT-PLAYER_HEIGHT-20;

    }
    public void drawPlayer(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(p2Image, y, heightPosition, main);
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {     
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
       int newX = me.getX();
       int newY = me.getY();
       if(newY > (Main.HEIGHT+PLAYER_HEIGHT+10)){
           y = Main.HEIGHT+PLAYER_HEIGHT+10;
       }else{
           y = newY;
       }
//       if (newX > (Main.WIDTH-PLAYER_WIDTH-10)){
//           x = Main.WIDTH-PLAYER_WIDTH-10;
//       }else{
//           x = newX;
//       }
    }
}
```

**Updated with Main...**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    public static int WIDTH = 600;
    public static int HEIGHT = 600;
    private int gameSpeed = 100;
    PlayerOne playOne = null;
    PlayerTwo playTwo = null;
    Image p1Image = null;
    Image p2Image = null;
    Image backImage = null;
    Graphics offscreen_high;
    BufferedImage offscreen;

    public Main(String frameTitle) {
        super(frameTitle);

        p1Image = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("src/resources/player1.gif").getImage();
        p2Image = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("src/resources/player2.gif").getImage();
        backImage = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("src/resources/back.png").getImage();

        offscreen = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        offscreen_high = offscreen.createGraphics();

        playOne = new PlayerOne(p1Image, this);
        playTwo = new PlayerTwo(p2Image, this);

        addKeyListener(playOne);
        addKeyListener(playTwo);

        addMouseListener(playTwo);
        addMouseMotionListener(playTwo);


        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);

        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        offscreen_high.setColor(Color.black);
        offscreen_high.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        offscreen_high.drawImage(backImage, 0, 0, this);
        playOne.drawPlayer(offscreen_high);
        playTwo.drawPlayer(offscreen_high);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
    }

//   public void update(Graphics g){
//       paint(g);
//   }
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(gameSpeed);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            repaint();
            count++;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main("Game On!");
    }

}
```

Comment: @FAST Things like "Please help me" and "Thanks in advance" don't really belong in posts. See [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Dukeling ,the post was almost code so it was not allowing me to share unless i add some text.

Comment: You're not actually calling `drawPlayer` from anywhere?

Comment: What is `Main`? Btw, if "almost only code" is a problem, don't add mindless text, remove code not relevant to the question. Having a bunch of empty methods is not relevant, you could have sufficed with a text stating "methods for interfaces removed for brevity" and instead add context to the question. What have you tried, what have you searched for and so on.

Comment: Im new to stack overflow so im not used to how things for around here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you need some way to tell the UI that it should be updated.

Assuming that `Main` is some kind of component (and it's also responsible for painting the `Player`), you should be calling its `repaint` method in the `mouseListener`

But without more details, this is more of a guess

**Updated**

After a muck around with the code, the main problem, as I see it, is your trying to draw the image only the horizontal axis (x) using the vertical position (y)...

```
public void drawPlayer(Graphics g){
    //g.drawImage(p2Image, y, heightPosition, main);
    g.drawImage(p2Image, x, heightPosition, main);
}
```

To get it to work, you're going to have to uncomment the code in you `mouseMoved` method so that the x position updates.

You should also avoid painting to top level containers, the main reason (apart from the fact that you can screw up the paint process) is that top level containers are not double buffered.

Instead, you should move your entire game container over to something like a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method (and don't for get to call super.paintComponent)

Comment: Main is just my main class

Comment: If you would like to have a look at my files in more detail here is my project http://www.mediafire.com/?7t4y9m5wfyt4kw9

Comment: how would i get it to move on the x and y axis

Comment: Replace heightPosition with y